# React unit test to find the element in the component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, enzyme

any help is appreciated. I was bit stuck with writing unit test in react. I need to check if action button and link button exists in the component.
here is my code for component. It is rendering child component and passing button as render props

```
export interface CloseableNotificationBannerProps {
    title?: string;
    message: string;
    variant: "default" ;
    icon: "info";
    actionButton?: React.ReactNode;
    showLinkButton: boolean;
}

export const CloseableNotificationBanner: React.FC<CloseableNotificationBannerProps> =
    ({
       title,
       message,
       variant,
       icon,
       actionButton,
       showLinkButton
     }) => {

  const [show, setShow] = useState(false); // extract into props to deafult it

  const handleClick = () => setShow(prevState => !prevState);

  return (
        show ?
          <BasicNotificationBanner
              title={title}
              message={message}
              variant={variant}
              icon={icon}
              actionButton={actionButton}
              closeButton={showLinkButton && <LinkButton
                  variant="transparent"
                  color="neutrals.dn40"
                  onClick={handleClick}>&times;</LinkButton>}
          /> : null
      );
};
```

For now It is able to mount the component successfully but unable to find action button and link button. Below is my unit test:

```
    // Given

      const content = {
          message: chance.string(),
          icon: chance.pickone(["info", "check_circle", "warning"]),
          variant: chance.pickone(["default", "information", "success", "error", "warning"]),
          actionButton: <Button>button</Button>,
          showLinkButton: true
      };
    // When
    const actual = mount(<CloseableNotificationBanner  content={content}/>);
    const button = actual.find(Button);
    // Then
    expect(actual.exists()).toBeTruthy();
    expect(button.exists()).toBeTruthy();
```

output shows that
Error: expect(received).toBeTruthy()

Received: false

for button. Please help. I have tried wit both shallow and render

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it using expect(actual.children().props().actionButton).toEqual(content.actionButton);

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do this is to use the
`toBeInTheDocument()` function.

Like this:

```
expect(actual).toBeInTheDocument();
expect(button).toBeInTheDocument();
```

Comment: `toBeInTheDocument` is not part of RTL. You need to install `jest-dom` to enable it.

Answer (score 0):

So, you need find particular button by its `id` or by its `class` name like

```
 expect(actual.find('#actionButton').length).toBe(1); // if it has actionButton id

 expect(actual.find('.button-class').at(0).length).toBe(1); // if its has many buttons and all have button-class and its on first position

 expect(actual.find('button').length).toBe(2); // 2, if you have only two buttons
```